# MYSQL split and update record for the same column

Tags: mysql, split, substring

I have a field in MySQL which contains a field named First name. Erroneously, the field was updated with Surname and First name with comma(,) between the names.

I want to update that filed running a MySQL command.

For example, my records are

Jack, Kallis
Mathew, Heyden

After the update command the fields will look like,

Kallis
Heyden

Thanks in advance.

Liton

Comment: What you wanna to update???can you tell in brief...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', -1 ) From table
```

For update :-

```
Update table SET name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', -1 )
```

[Read more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)